# Collision with Bitmap AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap

So I created a nice collision system shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVAU7Y0tc_I&user=badfitz66). Now I have my own character sprite, which has messed up the collision on all sides.

edit: because people are misunderstand what I want, I WANT it to overlap on the bottom and top, it gives it a 3D effect. My problem is that it's colliding incorrectly with the bitmap

I've tried using the pixel perfect collision system but I have a problem with it:

It only detects collision right at the edge, as you can see in the video, the ball can go slightly in front and behind the wall like it wasn't just a flat plane.

code responsible for the current collision (it did have some other stuff but that's been removed):

```
    for each (var wall in Walls)
    {
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y, true)) //col right
        {
            Character.x+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y, true)) //col left
        {
            Character.x-=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x , Character.y, true)) //col bottom
        {
            Character.y+=CharacterSpeed;
        }
        if (wall.hitTestPoint(Character.x, Character.y, true)) //col top
        {
            Character.y -= CharacterSpeed;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is correct (and I mean that's what the code does) and that effect depends on framerate as well.

The principle is easy to understand. ex: You move an object by 5 pixels, the colliding object is 3 pixels away, when you test for collision you have an overlap of 2 pixels. To correct this you need what's called a TOI (time of impact) algorithm.

As of right now there's no fixing your code because you apply a motion is the inverse way it's supposed to work. You move first then you test while the correct way is you test then you move. For example:

1. you are about to move the object by x pixels.
2. test if the object + x pixels will collide.
3. if it will collide calculate by how much you should move it then move it by x pixels - corrected pixels.
4. if it will not collide then move it by x pixels.

As you see you do the opposite:

1. move by x pixels.
2. test for collision.

The result is overlapping objects.

What you can do as a hack without changing your code is calculate the overlapping and then correct the object position.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I said. I WANT it to overlap on the bottom and top, like a pseudo 3D collision system in a 2D game. The problem I'm having is that it's not colliding correctly (collides too far away from wall, overlaps the sides etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can try draw your objects to a BitmapData using BitmapData.draw method, and than use BitmapData.hittest, here a sample:

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Point;

var myBitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 80, false, 0x00CCCCCC);

var mc_1:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
mc_1.attachBitmap(myBitmapData, this.getNextHighestDepth());

var mc_2:MovieClip = createRectangle(20, 20, 0xFF0000);

var destPoint:Point = new Point(myBitmapData.rectangle.x, myBitmapData.rectangle.y);
var currPoint:Point = new Point();

mc_1.onEnterFrame = function() {
    currPoint.x = mc_2._x;
    currPoint.y = mc_2._y;
    if(myBitmapData.hitTest(destPoint, 255, currPoint)) {
        trace(">> Collision at x:" + currPoint.x + " and y:" + currPoint.y);
    }
}

mc_2.startDrag(true);

function createRectangle(width:Number, height:Number, color:Number):MovieClip {
    var depth:Number = this.getNextHighestDepth();
    var mc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mc_" + depth, depth);
    mc.beginFill(color);
    mc.lineTo(0, height);
    mc.lineTo(width, height);
    mc.lineTo(width, 0);
    mc.lineTo(0, 0);
    return mc;
}
```